# Laravel 5.1 LTS multi tenancy

Tags: php, multi-tenant, laravel-5.1

I am fairly new to laravel, I have a project at hand with multi-tenancy needs. I saw this package https://github.com/laraflock/multi-tenant and I was interested in it until I saw it only allows for a database per tenant. I want to achieve a single database for the whole application separating tenants by ID. I already have my database structured. Is there anyone with an opinion on how best to achieve that with Laravel 5.1? I have seen so much on 4.2 but since I have not tried 4.2, I just skipped.